# Summation of differences in exponent

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

Came to this summation during an algorithm analysis problem and any help would be much appreciated:$$\sum_{j=1}^n3^{n-j}$$

Comment: It's same to $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} 3^j$. To see this just write down all the terms like $3^{n-1}+3^{n-2}+\cdots+3^1+3^0$.

Comment: $Sum=\frac{1}{2}(3^n-1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a geometric series.
$$\sum_{j=1}^n3^{n-j}=3^{n-1}+3^{n-2}+...$$
The first term is $3^{n-1}$, the common ratio is $\frac{1}{3}$, and there are $n$ terms. Thus,
$$\sum_{j=1}^n3^{n-j}=3^{n-1} \cdot \frac{1-(\frac{1}{3})^{n}}{1-\frac{1}{3}}$$
If a recursive algorithm is necessary, try

```
func(n)
{
    return n==0 ? 0 : (pow(3,n)+func(n-1));
}
```

Comment: $j$ is the summation variable. It should not appear on the final formula.

Comment: Many thanks, I'm still trying to wrap  my head around it but it makes sense now.

Comment: @JakubKawalec If you are not familiar with geometric series, that equation may seem mysterious. I suggest [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html) for the classical proof.

Comment: I'm familiar with the series just the $(n-j)$ was throwing me for a loop.

Comment: You can put the sum right into standard geometric series form with the transform $j \to n-j+1$. This just runs the sum backwards, but the $n$'s cancel with that substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\sum_{j=1}^n3^{n-j}=3^n\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{3^j}$$